# What is wrong with my two table sql Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select customerid in the envents table and where it is the same as the customerid in the customers' table and the session loginid equals the loginid in the customers table.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT event.customerid, customer.customerid,          
customer.loginid,customer.email". "FROM even, customer"."
WHERE event.customerid = customer.customerid  AND 
customer.loginid = ". $_SESSION['SESSLOGINID']);
```

Comment: Please, **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query` in new applications and *especially* not like this with unescaped data being injected directly into the query. This is extremely dangerous. [Proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Quick question tadman... I keep seeing this. This looks like an "example" style post. Every time I see someone post all of the code with proper security, everyone gripes at them to only post an example or relevant code. Again though... once they do, people like you immediately post a security "wrist slap". Any way we could get some consistency going? Maybe just answer the question and leave security to the OP? What if he is escaping it above the code posted? Just seems like folks with your experience would have better things to do.

Comment: Not to mention... it is coming from $_SESSION, not $_POST or $_GET. Seems like an odd response.

Answer (score 5):

missing space before FROM

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT event.customerid, customer.customerid,          
customer.loginid,customer.email". " FROM even, customer"."
WHERE event.customerid = customer.customerid  AND 
customer.loginid = ". $_SESSION['SESSLOGINID']);
```

edit:
and please don't ignore the comment of tadman

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a space between `customer.email` and `FROM`. You're also missing a `t` on `event`.

Your query should read:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT event.customerid, customer.customerid,          
customer.loginid,customer.email". " FROM event, customer"."
WHERE event.customerid = customer.customerid  AND 
customer.loginid = ". $_SESSION['SESSLOGINID']);
```

If you looked at the error message you were getting, you would at least get close to the problem. If you then looked carefully at the query (copy & paste to a variable and dump it), you should notice the problem.

---

Additional note: Before you go any further you should read about SQL injection if you have not already. Also, as @tadman points out, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used in new code.